# iptables -p all --dport

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

iptables doesn't seem to recognize `--dport` with `-p all`.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p all --dport www -j ACCEPT
```

yields:

```
iptables v1.4.4: unknown option `--dport'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

--destination-port doesn't work either: iptables v1.4.4: unknown option `--destination-port'
```

Adding two separate rules for `-p tcp` and `-p udp` works fine, so why doesn't it work for `-p all`?

In case it matters, this is on an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server with iptables package version 1.4.4-2ubuntu2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

--dport is not a flag for general iptables rules. It's a flag for one of it's *extended packet matching modules*. These are loaded when you use `-p protocol` or `-m`. Unless you specify `-m <protocol>` or `-p <protocol>` with a *specific protocol* you can't use `--dport`

You'll see this within the *iptables(8)* or *iptables-extensions(8)* manual page:

```
   tcp
       These extensions can be used if `--protocol tcp' is specified. It provides the
       following options:
       ...
       [!] --destination-port,--dport port[:port]
              Destination port or port range specification.  The flag --dport is a
              convenient alias for this option.
       ...
```

Not all protocols have a --dport flag because not all protocols support the notion of ports

Comment: This doesn't explain why wrt can support the usage of `-p all --dport`， see: https://serverfault.com/questions/307087/iptables-rules-for-dns-transparent-proxy-with-ip-exceptions

Answer (score 10):

'all' encompasses more than just TCP and UDP; it also covers protocols like ICMP which have no concept of port numbers, and thus can't take a --dport parameter.